# avoiding a duplicated output in PHP

Tags: php, duplicates, output

I have a problem on my script it *duplicates* the output from the **.html** file.
here is my code below.

php:

```
<?php
$html = file_exists('try.html') ? file_get_contents('try.html') : die('unable to open the file');

$data['test1'] = 'WRITE 1';

$data['test2'] = 'WRITE 2';

foreach ($data as $search => $value)
{
    if(preg_match_all('#(<([a-zA-Z]+)[^>]*id=")(.*'.$search.')("[^>]*>)([^<]*?)(</\\2>)#ism', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
    {
        foreach($matches as $match) 
        {
            $xhtml = str_replace($match[5],$value,$html);
            echo $xhtml;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TRY</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test1">A</div>
<div id="test2">B</div>
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT:

```
WRITE 1
B

A
WRITE 2
```

it duplicates the output.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
WRITE 1
WRITE 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this as your foreach loop:

```
foreach($matches as $match) 
{
    $xhtml = str_replace($match[5],$value,$html);
    echo $xhtml;
}
```

The echo is inside the loop, so you do one replacement each time, then echo $xhtml each time.  What you want is this:

```
<?php
$html = file_exists('try.html') ? file_get_contents('try.html') : die('unable to open the file');

$data['test1'] = 'WRITE 1';

$data['test2'] = 'WRITE 2';

foreach ($data as $search => $value)
{
    if(preg_match_all('#(<([a-zA-Z]+)[^>]*id=")(.*'.$search.')("[^>]*>)([^<]*?)(</\\2>)#ism', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
    {
        foreach($matches as $match) 
        {
            $html = str_replace($match[5],$value,$html);
        }
    }
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: quite confussing about the variable `$xhtml` thats why if I used it will only output a 1 variable value so you used `$html` to override it. thank you so much. I was just confused on variables.